# WiFi Direct Not working properly on Samsung Devices

Tags: java, android, wifi-direct, file-sharing, android-sharing

I am working on a project based on File sharing via WiFi. The problem i am facing is that Samsung devices are not receiving the files. Here is my Code.

```
private static final String TAG = MainReceiver.class.getName();
public static final String ACTION_TRANSFER_DONE = "action_transfer_done";
private MainActivity mActivity;
public MainReceiver(){
    super();
}

public MainReceiver(MainActivity activity){
    super();
    mActivity = activity;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    if (intent.getAction().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("action_transfer_done"))
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "transfer done");
        List<String> mFileNames = intent.getStringArrayListExtra(ServerService.FILES_NAME);
        mActivity.transferDone(mFileNames);
    }
}
```